# Data base column insertion when the strings of the columns do not match fully

Tags: sql, bigdata

I have a big data base (DatabaseA) with 120 millions of rows per part (billions and billions of rows). Per part and per row (120M), i do need find instances on DatabaseB (~10000 rows) into DatabaseA. The fundamental problem is that i do not see an easy and efficient way to do that with SQL. 
   The reason is the following: Column B on both columns matches exactly however, Column A does not have an specific order or logic. The only thing that i know it is that column A on DatabaseB is contained on column A on DatabaseA.
My data base expert wants to do it with SQL however, given the amount of rows, i do not think this will work. Any solution? suggestion? Much appreciated

```
    DatabaseA                                     DatabaseB 
ColumnA                        ColumnB         ColumnA           Column B
ttttttxdc/abbbbb/sssh/dddef    DXXXXA         sssh/dddef              DXXXXA
cccdft/ddd/sssh/dddef/xxxx      DXXXXA         sssh/dddef             DXXXXA
sssh/ddd/xxxx                   DXXXXB         sssh/ddd               DXXXXB
Vvvv/aaa/bbbb/dccc/tttt        DXXXXB           aaa/bbbb/tttt         DXXXXB
Vvvv/xxx/bbbb/rrrr/tttt        DXXXXB
```

Expected output

Output

```
DBA                                   DBB   
ColumnA                        ColumnB         ColumnC           Result
ttttttxdc/abbbbb/sssh/dddef    DXXXXA         sssh/dddef           matched   
cccdft/ddd/sssh/dddef/xxxx      DXXXXA          sssh/dddef             matched
sssh/ddd/xxxx                   DXXXXB         sssh/ddd               matched
Vvvv/aaa/bbbb/dccc/tttt        DXXXXB           aaa/bbbb/tttt         matched
Vvvv/xxx/bbbb/rrrr/tttt        DXXXXB                           unmatched
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include expected output for the example.

Comment: How many matches are returned if you only join on column B? The reason I ask is that it may be worthwhile splitting your problem into two parts: find matches on Column B and save to temp table, then match on column A. Do you have any indexes?

Comment: That might help to reduce basically the search. thanks, that is good suggestion

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Right now, i am using SQLite however, once the logic is good, we will move to Oracle since the database is too large